# Initiating same angularjs app in two places

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, zope

I have a html template that is being used for multiple projects. In that template I have two places where I can set the content.

The layout is something similar to this:

```
<body>
  <div>Navbar from TEMPLATE</div>
  <div>
    <div>other TEMPLATE stuff</div>
    <div id="content1">CONTENT can be set here</div>
  </div>
  <div id="content2">CONTENT can also be set here</div>
</body>
```

My question is is it possible to use the same angular app in both `#content1` and `#content2`? Can the `ng-app="main"` be used twice?

If something like this isn't possible to do I can add an `ng-app` attribute to the template but would rather not have to do this as, as I said, the template is used for multiple projects a lot of which won't be using angular.

**Edit**:
Just to clarify, I'm using a tal template from zope. In that template I have two fill slots, I would like to use the same angular app in both fill slots without having to change the original tal template if possible.

Comment: I think you are probably missing the point of angularjs. If you want to reuse templates in your app (or multiple apps for that matter), you should look into directives, and maybe inject a common directives module to both of your apps.

Comment: @Tomer I'm not trying to use a template within an angular app. I'm using angular in a section of a predefined template.